# Detect user picked up phone outgoing call with kdtele in .net

Tags: c#, .net

I have an app that use `kdtele` component for communicating with  the phones.

When I make a call, and the end user pick up the phone, `OnVoiceDetected`event don't fire. I use intel3chips v.92 modems.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I appears that [Kaed Systems, the makers of KDTele, offer technical support](http://www.kaed.com/contact.html). I suspect you will not find much help here on StackOverflow because KDTele is not widely known; the authors of KDTele are more likely to be able to help you.